# php just stopped working /malfunctioning. displaying source code

Tags: php

I am trying to run this simple php code (in a file named "database.php")

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
        $servername = 'localhost';
        $username = 'admin';
        $password = 'admin1';

     //Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
    // Check connection

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error);

                             } 
else { 

echo 'Connected Successfully.' ;

     }

$conn->close();

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

AND HERE IS THE OUTPUT IN MY BROWSER

```
connect_error)  
{ die('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error); } 
else { echo 'Connected Successfully.' ; } 
$conn->close();
?>
```

( the first part of php code get processed but later it shows just the source code)

PLEASE HELP.

Comment: Install a web server with PHP.

Comment: You also need to pass a 4th parameter `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am running wamp server and PHP worked quite well until a few hours back.. it was successfully connecting to database but suddenly it stopped working. Thanks in advance. please help

Comment: tried that here is my new code.. still same output..<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'admin';
$password = 'admin1';
$db_name = 'azadhind';
 //Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);
// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error);

} 
else { 
echo 'Connected Successfully.' ;
}

$conn->close();

?>

Comment: This sort of issue doesn't generally "suddenly stop working" without some intervention on your part. Did you modify the server config?

Comment: no did not do anything .. except a power failure.. I don't think that has to do anything with the server config.

Comment: Did you guys note that the script is processed until it reaches the "connect_error) .......

Comment: @KaNcH probably I can't see your answer.. where is it? which one?

Comment: @RameshPareek their is a code last answer.

Comment: @RameshPareek Bhai sorry .. Ek bar aur try kar le .. ho jayega

Comment: If it worked before, then restart all services.

Comment: @Ramesh - changing the code will NOT fix it. NONE of your code is being executed, see my explanation why some code is invisible below. For whatever reason, Apache is not processing PHP. If you had a power failure, perhaps a config file was corrupted or something.

Comment: "Did you guys note that the script is processed until it reaches the "connect_error)" View source and you'll find this isn't true. Your browser is seeing `<?php` as an opened HTML tag that doesn't close until the `>` in the `connect_error` line.

Answer (score 1):

Set a handler for *.php files in the webserver config. For apache:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: how do I do that , I am using wampserver

Comment: Not really familiar with wampserver, but I know it uses apache. Also have no idea why it's not set by default. You should look for a conf or conf.d directory with httpd.conf in it. My snipped should be placed inside  <Directory /> tag.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the code is not actually being processed, but being hidden because the browser thinks it is an HTML tag. So everything between `<?` and `->` gets hidden. A viktike points out, you need to enable PHP parsing by your server, which may require additionally a number of actions beyond simply adding PHP handing in the sercver config.

I'm not familiar with Wamp, but it seems like PHP has been disabled so I'd explore re-enabling, starting with simply restarting the server, and then looking at Apache config and Wamp's own method of configuring things which probably departs from standard method of doing this stuff.